# Test-Path returns true but Remove-Item could not find path

Tags: powershell

I'm creating a script in PowerShell which is supposed to find a user's UPM folder and append .old to it (to facilitate a profile rebuild).

The snippet below is the code that I have:

```
# Rename the UPM profile
Exit-PSSession
cd '\\SYLX-FS-01\D$\UPMProfiles'
$UPMPath = "$target.upm"
$UPMOld = "$target.upm.old"
if (Test-Path $UPMPath -IsValid) {
    if (Test-Path $UPMOld -IsValid) {
        Remove-Item $UPMOld
        Rename-Item $UPMPath -NewName $UPMOld
        Write-Host "Renamed UPMProfile"
    } else {
        Rename-Item $UPMPath -NewName $UPMOld
        Write-Host "Renamed UPMProfile"
    }
} else {
    # Write-Host "UPM Profile not found, no action has been taken on the file server."
    $UPM = "False"
}
```

Every time I run this it returns an error that the file could not be found.

```
Remove-Item : Cannot find path '\\SYLX-FS-01\D$\UPMProfiles\bill.odwyer.upm.old'
because it does not exist.
At line:8 char:20
+         Remove-Item <<<<  $UPMOld
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\SYLX-FS-01...er.upm.old:String) [Remove-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

As far as I can tell, it should only be going to line 8 if the `$UPMPath` exists, and if not then it should just skip to `else`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you drop the flag "-IsValid" it should work.

IsValid returns true if the path itself is a valid (legal) path. It doesn't check if the file/folder exists.

If you drop the -IsValid the Test-path checks and returns true/false if the path exists or not.

Read more on: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849776.aspx

Answer (score 3):

`Test-Path -IsValid` checks if a path specification is valid, not if the path actually exists. Remove the parameter `-IsValid` to verify the existence of a path.

From the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849776.aspx):

> **-IsValid**
>   Determines whether the syntax of the path is correct, regardless of whether the elements of the path exist. This parameter returns TRUE if the path syntax is valid and FALSE if it is not.